# keycloak initial login does not work with admin username and password

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I cannot login to keycloak in the initial setup. I managed to run the server via /standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0 command and when accessing it via http://x.x.x.x:8080 the login page doesn't allow me to login with admin/admin username and password. any hint is highly apreciated.

Comment: I sorted it out with the command add-user-keycloak and restarting server.

Comment: Please delete this question or provide a detailed answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

According to the latest keycloak documentation (today) there are two procedures for creating the first administrator credentials:

**Creating the account on the local host**

If your server is accessible from localhost, perform these steps.
Procedure:

1. In a web browser, go to the http://localhost:8080 URL.
2. Supply a username and password that you can recall in the    Welcome page
   [image]

**Creating the account remotely**

If you cannot access the server from a localhost address, or just want to start Keycloak from the command line, use the KEYCLOAK_ADMIN and KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD environment variables to create an initial admin account.

For example:

```
export KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=<username>
export KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=<password>

bin/kc.[sh|bat] start
```

Comment: Do these env var names still apply in version 20?

Comment: @dingo I've just used the second approach on a 23.0.6 version of keycloak.

Answer (score 9):

In order to create the initial *administrator* user you need to use `add-user-keycloak.sh` (.bat) script located in `keycloak/bin` with all other scripts. Run it before starting/restarting the server, so Keycloak could pick up the user: 
`$ ./add-user-keycloak.sh -u admin -p password`.

`$ ./add-user-keycloak.sh --help` will show you all the available options.

Comment: `add-user-keycloak.sh ` this script is no more available in the distribution/installation anymore.  Is there any other way to set up the initial admin account

Comment: @TarunPatel this is the right answer in 2021

Answer (score -1):

If you are someone who have setup KeyCloak in **Kubernetes** then we can **port-forward** and access the localhost:8080/auth that is how I did the initial admin user setup.

```
kubectl port-forward svc/keycloak-http  -n <namespace> 8080:80
```